# In JMeter while running with same thread group configuration for 2 times it's showing different results in aggregate listener

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am new to jmeter. In JMeter while running with same thread group configuration for 2 times it's showing different results in aggregate listener. While running 1st time it's showing 0% error results, 2nd time it's showing some error percentage with same thread group configurations which we used to run on first time. Why it's showing 2 different results for same configuration.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know, on well-behaved system the same test should produce the same results given [test repeatability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability) criteria are met (i.e. tests leave system at the same state)

You can consider temporarily [enabling saving requests and responses data](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter/) either by amending [Results File configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) to look like:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
```

or adding a listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) configured like:

[image]

once you re-run your test you can inspect the .jtl results file using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspect request and response details, most probably you will be able to figure out the failures reason. It's also a good idea to check the application under test log files.